# SQL check whether A and B IN (...)

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have a messaging system which stores messages using these columns:

- message, which is the actual message
- to_id, id of the user that'll receive the message
- from_id, id of the user that sent the message

I want to query a conversation like this:

```
SELECT sender.username, message
FROM messages
JOIN users sender ON sender.id=messages.from_id
JOIN users receiver ON receiver.id=messages.to_id
WHERE (sender.username LIKE 'user1' AND receiver.username LIKE 'user2')
OR (receiver.username LIKE 'user1' AND sender.username LIKE 'user2')
```

which works, but I'd like to pass *user1* and *user2* only once, something like

```
WHERE (from_id, to_id) IN ((SELECT id FROM users WHERE username LIKE 'user1'),
(SELECT id FROM users WHERE username LIKE 'user2'))
```

which doesn't work in mysql. any suggestions?

Comment: Unless you don’t actually need `LIKE` and can instead use `=`, I think your original method is probably the best one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using tuples:

```
SELECT sender.username, message
FROM messages m JOIN
     users sender
     ON sender.id = m.from_id JOIN
     users receiver
     ON receiver.id = m.to_id
WHERE ('user1', 'user2') in ( (sender.username, receiver.username), 
                              (receiver.username, sender.username), 
                            );
```

This should make no difference from a performance perspective.

Comment: The query plan should be verified.  Historically, this construct has resulted in a full table scan, because the optimizer doesn't understand the implications and the expression gets evaluated very late, `using where`.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot . . . The original code would also result in a full table scan.  Avoiding that requires rewriting the query for performance, and that is not the OP's objective.

Comment: With that thought in mind, you're absolutely correct, it should make no difference. :)